# Correctly Formatting Time for Document Title

Tags: javascript

I have the below code loaded in the head of a small HTML file. It is meant to grab the current time, convert it to 12H, add am or pm and then set this as the document title. This appears to work as I want, until the final line where I want it to run the function every 5 seconds so the document title updates dynamically. For whatever reason this isn't working and I can't figure out why. Can anyone assist?

```
function tConv24(time24) {
    var ts = time24;
    var H = +ts.substr(0, 2);
    var h = (H % 12) || 12;
    h = (h < 10)?("0"+h):h;
    var ampm = H < 12 ? " am" : " pm";
    ts = h + ts.substr(2, 3) + ampm;
    return ts;
}

var today = new Date();
var currentTime = today.getHours() + ":" + today.getMinutes();
document.title = tConv24(currentTime);

setInterval(tConv24(currentTime), 5000);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logic seems fine, except that `currentTime` is only initialized once. So, the function `tConv24` is being called each time with the same value. To correct, you need to make sure you always grab the latest date time by using the `Date` constructor:

```js
function tConv24(time24) {
  // function implementation
}

setInterval(function() {
  var today = new Date();
  var currentTime = today.getHours() + ":" + today.getMinutes();
  document.title = tConv24(currentTime);
}, 5000);
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this out:

```js
let doc, bod, I, displayTime; // for use on other loads
addEventListener('load', ()=>{
doc = document; bod = doc.body;
I = id=>doc.getElementById(id);
displayTime = ()=>{
  let dt = new Date, hr = dt.getHours(), mn = dt.getMinutes(), pm = 'am';
  if(hr > 12){
    hr -= 12; pm = 'pm';
  }
  if(mn.toString().length < 2)mn = '0'+mn;
  return hr+':'+mn+pm;
}
const test = I('test');
test.textContent = displayTime();
setInterval(()=>{
  test.textContent = displayTime();
}, 1000);
});
```

```html
<div id='test'></div>
```